# Run R with no gui

Tags: php, r, rscript

I am trying to get a default installed `CentOS7 R 3.2.3` running without GUI, just for the data processing. The following code runs fine on OSX with no gui output, but fails on CentOS. I start both as

`Rscript script.r someMatrix.txt`

```
theMatrix = as.matrix(read.table(args[1],header=TRUE,sep="\t",row.names = 1))
values = heatmap(theMatrix,keep.dendro=TRUE)

Error in dev.hold() : no active or default device
Calls: heatmap -> dev.hold
```

I am calling the R scirpt from a PHP script within Apache. So it maybe a bad environment setting for the Apache user, but I am using the system wide installed package, and running the script as another user without any special environment settings worked fine.

Comment: `su apache` then run your program, does it work?

Comment: I am assuming that `heatmap` produces a graphic output by default: Maybe your R session then does not know where to put the output, i.e. which device to use. If this is so you may have to direct the graphic output into a device explicitly. In the docs for `grDevices::png` you find examples how to do that.

Comment: What I didnt notice was that the sucessfull runs always create a pdf in the same folder.  'su apache' fails because the apache user is by default no normal login user...